# Adding a total column to a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this csv, how do I add a Total column at the right?

```
Month,Jo, Bo, Mo, Flo
2101,130,154,88,99
2102,80,132,144,75
2103,90,142,160,98
2104,166,215,168,3
2105,80,125,221,180
2106,241,315,264,127
```

```
earnings_data.loc[:,'Total'] = earnings_data.iloc[1:].sum()
```

gives key error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\rorym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py",
> line 391, in get_loc
>     `return self._range.index(new_key)`
>            `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

Comment: You need do `.iloc[:, 1:]`